# errors: Index out of range exception unhandled and Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'int'

Tags: c#, arrays, exception

i am getting 'Index out of range exception unhandled' in my form1.i will be pointing it out by comments.i am showing you only the part of the code where i use the following declarations.

here is my form1

```
    Int32 u, v;
    int32[] l = new int32[2];
    int32[] m = new int32[2];
    int32[] g = new int32[2];
    int32[] h = new int32[2];
    int TwoClicks = 0;

    private WindowsFormsApplication2.Form2 _form2 = new WindowsFormsApplication2.Form2();

    private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (TwoClicks < 2)
        {
             TwoClicks++;

        DialogResult dialogresult = _form2.ShowDialog(this);


        if (dialogresult == DialogResult.OK)
        {

                rect.Width = 0;
                rect.Height = 0;
                pictureBox1.Invalidate();

                l[TwoClicks] = e.X;// I am getting the exception here
                m[TwoClicks] = e.Y;


        }
        if (dialogresult == DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            rect.Width = 0;
            rect.Height = 0;
            pictureBox1.Invalidate();
            TwoClicks--;
        }


        }
    }


    private void pictureBox1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        int radius = 10; //Set the number of pixel you want to use here
        //Calculate the numbers based on radius
        int x0 = Math.Max(e.X - (radius / 2), 0),
            y0 = Math.Max(e.Y - (radius / 2), 0),
            x1 = Math.Min(e.X + (radius / 2), pictureBox1.Width),
            y1 = Math.Min(e.Y + (radius / 2), pictureBox1.Height);
        Bitmap bm = pictureBox1.Image as Bitmap; //Get the bitmap (assuming it is stored that way)
        for (int ix = x0; ix < x1; ix++)
        {
            for (int iy = y0; iy < y1; iy++)
            {
                bm.SetPixel(ix, iy, Color.Black); //Change the pixel color, maybe should be relative to bitmap
            }
        }
        pictureBox1.Refresh(); //Force refresh

            u = (e.X - l[0]) * (g[1] - g[0]) / (l[1] - l[0]);
            v = (e.Y - m[0]) * (h[1] - h[0]) / (m[1] - m[0]);

        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("latitude is {0} degrees {1} minutes and longitude is {2} degrees {3} minutes", u / 60, u % 60, v / 60, v % 60));
    }
```

I am getting this error : Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'int' in my form2 which i use as a custom message box.
there are also few other errors which im getting.

--->Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'WindowsFormsApplication2.int32'

--->Operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'WindowsFormsApplication2.int32' and 'WindowsFormsApplication2.int32'

--->Operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and  WindowsFormsApplication2.int32'

Here is my Form2

```
    int32[] g = new int32[3];
    int32[] h = new int32[3];
    int TwoClicks = 0;

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            g[TwoClicks] = (int32.Parse(textBox1.Text) * 60 + int32.Parse(textBox2.Text));
            h[TwoClicks] = (int32.Parse(textBox3.Text) * 60 + int32.Parse(textBox4.Text));

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Your `int[]` are of size 2, so the highest index is 1 (0 based indexing). You are incrementing `TwoClicks` to 2 though.
2. The correct name is `Int32`, not `int32`.

Comment: should i replace 2 with 3 instead?

Comment: If index 2 is too high, surely 3 will be as well? Please read up on 0 based indexing.

Comment: g[TwoClicks] = (Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text) * 60 + Int32.Parse(textBox2.Text));
                h[TwoClicks] = (Int32.Parse(textBox3.Text) * 60 + Int32.Parse(textBox4.Text)); these lines are showing Format exception Unhandled!!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse.aspx You need to supply a NumberFormat if you are using a custom culture. (ie. `,` for decimal seperation).

Comment: I have to retrieve the values from the textboxes  and convert those values to minutes( those are latitude and longitudes).

Answer (score 1):

Arrays have 0 based indexs. Check if `TwoClicks` variable is getting value 2 or more it will result in that exception

Comment: It would result in indexoutofrange exception. But OP is talking about conversion error.

Comment: that's the second bug in the code. The first one is indexoutofrange.

Answer (score 1):

```
int32[] l = new int32[2];
int32[] m = new int32[2];
int32[] g = new int32[2];
int32[] h = new int32[2];
```

I am guessing int32 is some custom class. As there is no built in keyword 'int32'. You must use int or Int32 for mathematical operations. Else the framework wont automatically cast for operators.

Comment: ya you are correct I changed it!! but iam geting format exception unhandled in this piece of code.
g[TwoClicks] = (Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text) * 60 + Int32.Parse(textBox2.Text));
                h[TwoClicks] = (Int32.Parse(textBox3.Text) * 60 + Int32.Parse(textBox4.Text));

Comment: It means that `Text` in one of your textboxes is not numer - can't be parsed

Comment: ya in the text box i  should enter some numerical value, now how can i use that numerical value in further calculations.